# MUI styled avoid writing shouldForwardProp every time

Tags: material-ui, styled-components

When we use styled-components from MUI, to use custom props, we gotta write like this:

```
const Title = styled(Typography, { shouldForwardProp: prop => prop !== 'isMain' })<{ isMain: boolean }>`....
```

To prevent error that React doesnt'recognize .....
Maybe there is some good solution not to write this long declaration, some root configuration for this?